# gen files in all Projects gone ( R.java missing)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file, missing-data

im facing a strange problem in eclipse adt. I wanted to clean up my workspace and deleted all the double appcombat v7 files, and wanted to keep only one of it. it seemed that eclipse always generated a new folder for that.

so after doing so, all my projects crushed...the R.Java Files are missing and nothing works at all. already tried to reimpost the appcombat v7 files, eclipse is arguing there too.

At the beginning Eclipse tells me i aint got the newest version, but i downloaded and installed elipse without any better achievement.

Cleaning did not work for me, i also installed eclipse new, no changes too
HELP!HELP!HELP

Comment: Try to check if your projects are referencing an `appcompatv7` project in the project properties. Select your project folder, go to `Android` tab on the left, check the library list in the bottom part of the main window. Sometimes Eclipse removes the R file when there's a mistake in the layout, and a missing appcompatv7 reference screws up your layout.

Comment: It keeps coming back because it is added as library reference to one of your projects. Find and remove it. And try a fresh start by importing it because you most probably messed it up. remove any faulty projects and import again. and see "Problems" tab in eclipse to find out what's really happening. and yeah, Please don't yell HELP! HELP! We are programmers, not 9 year old girls.

Comment: import another project and check error are ther in new project

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, finally i reimportet the file from an older version. that did it for me :)